# Recursion - if there is continuity of numbers in java

Tags: java, recursion

I have an exercise I get an error and would love to help on the error and how to fix exercise.

> Write a recursive function that receives a set of numbers and a number
>   between 9-1. The function returns true if there is a continuity of
>   numbers from 1 to the number, otherwise returns false.

It always brings me true, there is no error.

> Examples:
>
> For the array `3,1,2,3,4,6,3` and number `4` is returned to `true`
>
> For the array `3,1,2,1,2,3,5` and number `4` is returned `false`

The code:

```
public static boolean continuityOfnumbers(int[] arr, int n) {
    int counter = 0;
    int index = arr.length - 1;

    if (n == 0)
            return true;

    if (arr[index] - 1 == arr[index - 1])
        counter += 1;

    index--;

    return continuityOfnumbers(arr, n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Look at your code: All it ever does is either `return true;` or return the result of a recursive call to itself. Now ask: Since it only ever returns `true` or the result of calling itself, how could it ever return `false`?

Comment: Quick suggestion: you pass a variable `n` and use it for the "return true" stop condition of your recursion. However you never use it for the recursion step. Try removing `counter` and `index`, then use more of that `n`.

Comment: Your larger problem is that you only ever look at the last element in the array anyways.  You need to do one of two things each time: move the "start" point (where the `1` is supposed to be) forward one, or look at the next element after that, with an increased comparison value.

Comment: I'm unsure about the interpretation of *"continuity of numbers from 1 to the number"*. The examples don't fully cover it. Does it mean that there has to be a contiguous sequence of `1,2,3,4` somewhere in the array, or does it simply mean that the numbers `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4` just have to be present somewhere in the array? Your code seems to indicate the first option.

Comment: you asked, received three replies and never picked an answer or gave comments, this is considered rude in so

Answer (score 0):

Your example code always returns true, because that is the only value it ever returns. Basically, your method calls itself recursively with `n-1` until `n = 0` and `return true`.

You would need to divide the problem into the following subproblems:

Continuity for number `n` means

1. Continuity for number `n-1`
2. `n` is contained in the array

```
public static boolean continuityOfnumbers(Integer[] arr, int n) {
    if (n == 0)
        return true;
    return continuityOfnumbers(arr, n - 1) && contains(arr, n);
}

private static boolean contains(Integer[] arr, Integer n) {
    return Arrays.asList(arr).contains(n);
}
```

I used Integer[] instead of int[] just to write the *contains* part in one line. It is about code simplicity, not efficiency. And it is about how to use recursion in a simple way.

However, if your problem requires the numbers 1-n to be in order, this is not the correct solution.

Comment: I don't think this is the solution. The recursion is supposed to break and return true when the number is found, and false otherwise. Continously calling contains makes this an `O(n^2)` solution

Comment: I would reverse the order of the return statement so if a number was missing you stop recusing sooner.

Comment: And besides the n^2 problem, it's not going to actually make sure the numbers are in order anyways.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse The example in the question makes it quite clear that numbers are not required to be in order: *For the array `3,1,2,3,4,6,3` and number `4` is returned to `true`*. The only way for that example to work, is that the test is simply verifying *presence* of numbers 1-4. Second example fails because number `4` is not present.

Comment: Question uses an `int[]`, but you changed that to `Integer[]`, without reason or explanation. My guess is so you can do `Arrays.asList(arr).contains(n)`, but that's just lazy, requiring the overhead of a boxed array so you can write in one line what would be a simple `for` loop.

Comment: @Andreas *Continuity* implies that 4 can be reached through values of 1,2,and 3. If 1,2, or 3 did not exist in the first list, but 4 did, it would still be false.

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, which is why I said "test presence of numbers 1 thru 4" aka *"continuity of numbers from 1 to the number"*. If all 4 numbers are present, return true. If a number is missing, return false. --- As for your comment about `O(n^2)`, it's meaningless to the assignment. The assignment is about learning recursion, not about implementing the best performing solution.

Comment: @Andreas - There's two problems with that.  1) The example you're citing actually has 1-4 **in order**.  2) The O(n) is probably easier to implement (assuming the numbers have to be in order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `O(n)` runtime and storage complexity solution. It makes a boolean continuity array and checks it and the end of the recursion.

<sup>Don't just copy-paste it, make sure you read the comments in the code to see what the logic is, and make sure you understand it.</sup>

It additionally does some pre-validation checks to make sure that `n` is actually contained and reachable in the array before doing the recursion.

```
private static boolean continuityOfnumbers(int[] arr, int n) {
    // Max sure we can reach N
    if (n >= arr.length) return false;

    // Make sure N is in the array
    boolean findN = false;
    // Also find the max value in the array
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int x : arr) {
        if (x == n) findN = true;
        if (max < x) max = x;
    }
    // If N is not found or we still cant reach N, return false
    if (!findN || n > max) return false;

    // Build a continuity array of all false
    boolean[] contArr = new boolean[n];

    // Start recursion
    return continuityOfnumbers(arr, n, contArr, 0);
}

private static boolean continuityOfnumbers(int[] arr, int n, boolean[] contArr, int index) {
    // Base case - we reached the end of the array
    if (index >= arr.length) {
        // Check that all values up to N are true
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (!contArr[i]) return false;
        }
        // Here, we know the values are continuous
        return true;
    }

    // Set the index of the continuity array to a non-zero value
    int val = arr[index];
    if (val <= n && !contArr[val-1]){
        contArr[val-1] = true;
    }

    // Recurse with the next index
    return continuityOfnumbers(arr, n, contArr, index+1);
}
```

For the function `3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 3` with `n = 4`, here is a sample debug run with `0` being `false` and `true` being `1`.

```
start:  [0, 0, 0, 0]
Set 3:  [0, 0, 1, 0]
Set 1:  [1, 0, 1, 0]
Set 2:  [1, 1, 1, 0]
Set 4:  [1, 1, 1, 1]
true
```

And the same numbers with `n = 6` (should return `false` since `5` doesn't not exist).

```
start:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
Set 3:  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
Set 1:  [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
Set 2:  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
Set 4:  [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
Set 6:  [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]
false
```

Comment: Since you only need to check for presence of numbers 1-4 (index 0-3), then there's no need to create array of size 6. Size 4 is enough, and since you only care about existence, a `boolean` array is more appropriate that `int` array of 0 and 1 values, e.g. `boolean[] found`. --- Since you were so interested in performance in your comment to other answer, why always iterate the entire list, when you can stop scanning once all 4 values are detected as present?

Comment: Good point on the `boolean[]`, I guess I was stuck in C mode. I thought about the early returning once the value of `n` was seen, just didn't think too hard over if it was necessary to go further or not. And I think I only scan a max of 3 times, not always?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is, as others have stated, that you never return false, so you receive always true.

This is, because you never handle the case properly when you found a starting number but the sequence is not complete. You need to reset the search values then and start over from the position you failed.

In the following code, `set` is the set of numbers you are inspecting, `initial` is the starting number of the sequence. `search` is the number to search next (the next number in the sequence). `lastIdx` is the index in the array, we are currently looking at.

The stop condition is reaching either the end of sequence (success, search == 1 is at lastIdx in set) or if the lastIdx reaches the end of the set (fail, lastIdx < 0).

A special role is the `step` variable. The `step` is neccessary when you reset a partial sequence: The position you are currently looking at needs to be inspected again, if it is the start of the next sequence. If you have not started the sequence, the index has already been examined and you need to advance to the next.

The set is traversed from end to front, since you did the same in your approach.

```
boolean continuityOfNumber(int[] set, int initial, int search, int lastIdx) {
    if(lastIdx < 0)
        return false;

    if( set[lastIdx] == search ) {
        if( search == 1 )
            return true;

        return continuityOfNumber(set, initial, search - 1, lastIdx - 1);
    }

    int step = (initial == search) ? 1 : 0;

    return continuityOfNumber(set, initial, initial, lastIdx - step);
}


final int[] testSet = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0};
final int[] testSet2 = {0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0};
assertTrue(con.continuityOfNumber(testSet, 4, 4, testSet.length-1));
assertFalse(con.continuityOfNumber(testSet2, 4, 4, testSet2.length-1));
```